# JOptionPane.showInputDialog()

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So I have the method `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` which returns a String that is the value input by the user.
The Dialog box has an OK and a Cancel button.
How can I check so that I know whether the user clicked OK or Cancel?

Comment: there aren't another correct answer as posted by (@Крысa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` will return the string the user has entered if the user hits ok, and returns `null` otherwise. Therefore, you can just check to see if the resultant string is `null`. The javadocs on the method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) are not terribly explicit about this, but where the return behavior is mentioned, it is indicated to be so.

Comment: So if the user fills in the text field but clicks cancel, it returns null?

Comment: @Yokhen yes, it does, you can always verify yourself by printing out the raw result from the call, as well

Comment: +1, for the first answer and for suggesting that the poster can easily test this.

Answer (score 2):

From Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
Returns:
    user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input
```